# drawRect:/renderInContext: issues

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, exc-bad-access, drawrect

Seem to be having a bit of an issue trying to draw my view into a context.

My basic setup is, I have a view controller that owns a `UIPageViewController` in which I load controllers with views that can be drawn on by the users finger. Basically I have a book that can be drawn in.

When the page is turned in the book I save the image by calling

```
- (UIImage *)wholeImage {
    // Render the layer into an image and return
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *wholePageImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return wholePageImage;
}
```

The return value of this then gets saved to a file. However when I call this save method then line

```
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

gets hit, which seems to make a call to my `drawRect:` method, which is overridden as follows,

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Draw the current state of the image
    [self.currentImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
    CGPoint midPoint1 = [self midPointOfPoint1:previousPoint1 point2:previousPoint2];
    CGPoint midPoint2 = [self midPointOfPoint1:currentPoint point2:previousPoint1];

    // Get the context
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

    // Add the new bit of line to the image
    [self.layer renderInContext:context];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, midPoint1.x, midPoint1.y);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, midPoint2.x, midPoint2.y); 
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
    if (self.drawMode == LNDrawViewDrawModeTipex) CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
    else CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColour.CGColor);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    // Call super
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

which makes sense, but it seems to get called recursively until eventually I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this line

```
[self.currentImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
```

Am at a complete loss as to what is causing this and has been driving me nuts.

If it helps, my call stack starts like this

[image]

and then goes on recursively until it finally ends with

[image]

Would really appreciate and help and insight that anyone can give!!

EDIT: (Touches moved added)

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Get the touch
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    // Get the points
    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    // Calculate mid point
    CGPoint mid1 = [self midPointOfPoint1:previousPoint1 point2:previousPoint2]; 
    CGPoint mid2 = [self midPointOfPoint1:currentPoint point2:previousPoint1];

    // Create a path for the last few points
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
    CGRect pathBounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);
    CGPathRelease(path);

    // Take account of line width
    pathBounds.origin.x -= self.lineWidth * 2.0f;
    pathBounds.origin.y -= self.lineWidth * 2.0f;
    pathBounds.size.width += self.lineWidth * 4.0f;
    pathBounds.size.height += self.lineWidth * 4.0f;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pathBounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    self.currentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:pathBounds];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not call `[self.layer renderInContext:]` in `drawRect:`, period. As you have figured out, `renderInContext:` calls `drawRect:` if it is implemented, which will cause an infinite recursion.

You should render a book as is separately, then use the rendered image to let users draw on top of it. One way to do that is to enclose a self-contained drawing code in the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`/`UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` block and use the resulting image in `drawRect:`. Another way is to use two different views which are not subviews of each other, one drawing an unaltered book, the other drawing user sketches.

EDIT: first of all, you need an original image (book page, whatever). Draw it inside a `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`/`UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` block *without calling* `[self.layer renderInContext:]` and save it in the view's ivar (say, `self.currentImage`). In `touchesMoved:withEvent:` call `setNeedsDisplay` (it will call `drawRect:` for you) to update the view. Use `self.currentImage` in `drawRect:` as the background image.

I hope I'm not too vague.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Don;t think I'm entirely sure what you mean. Have just added my touches moved code to the question. I do some draw code in a UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()/UIGraphicsEndImageContext() block, but unless I call renderInContext again in the drawRect I seem to get some quite bazaar behaviour..?

Comment: It seems that drawRect does not always get called from renderInContext as I seem to be able to draw fine onto my view without this problem...!? Am very confused.

Comment: I think you got your architecture a bit wrong. Basically, you need to do two unrelated things: draw an image and draw something on top of it. Since they are independent, the view which draws the final result should take the original/background image somewhere else, rather than from its own content. The result of `drawRect:` is set as the view's layer's `contents`. `renderInContext:` may or may not call `drawRect:` each time, depending on a lot of factors outside of your control. It may use the cached image, but it is an implementation detail.

Comment: I see. You can also render user drawing into an image and then draw the image in `drawRect:`. When drawing into an image, you can use the result of previous drawing as the background, accumulating drawing operations. `drawRect:` in this case would just always draw the final image.

Comment: Sorry just saw your update. The problem is I can't get the original image without calling [self.layer renderInContext:] as the "original image" is actually just what has already been drawn into the layer?

Comment: Sorry for being such a pain, but how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Think I have worked out how to do what you said. THANKS!! When you do [self.layer renderInContext:] it puts the whole layer into the context. Is there a way to only render part of the layer into a context??

Comment: Sure, use Core Graphics clipping paths, see CGContext.h

Comment: Worked it out in the end. Thanks!!