# Draw line via Coregraphic: crash at renderInContext

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-graphics, xcode10, ios12

I'm using CoreGraphics to draw a line. I have just updated Xcode 10 and iOS 12. In iOS 12, my Application is crashed. Although, it still works well in iOS 11.4.1 and version before. I am not able to solve the issue. please find my code below

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2); 
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y); 
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);

    CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(-16.00, -5.0f), 5.0f);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    [super drawRect:rect];
    [curImage release];
}
```

Below is the `touchesMoved` method.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch  = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint2  = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1  = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    currentPoint    = [touch locationInView:self];

    // calculate mid point
    CGPoint mid1    = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2); 
    CGPoint mid2    = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, mid1.x, mid1.y);
    CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
    CGRect bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);
    CGPathRelease(path);

    CGRect drawBox = bounds;

    //Pad our values so the bounding box respects our line width
    drawBox.origin.x        -= self.lineWidth * 2;
    drawBox.origin.y        -= self.lineWidth * 2;
    drawBox.size.width      += self.lineWidth * 4;
    drawBox.size.height     += self.lineWidth * 4;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawBox.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    curImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [curImage retain];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:drawBox];

}

CGPoint midPoint(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2)
{
    return CGPointMake((p1.x + p2.x) * 0.5, (p1.y + p2.y) * 0.5);
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    previousPoint2 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

The issue is code crash at `[self.layer renderInContext:context];` of `(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` function. drawRect function is called too much time (About 5000 times) and Overload of Memory (About 20Gb) cause crashing app. 
Could there be changes in iOS 12 and Xcode 10?

I Fixed this issue.
Update my new toucheMoved() function:

```
- (void) touchesMoved: (NSSet*) touches withEvent: (UIEvent*) event
{    
previousPoint2 = previousPoint;
previousPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
location = [touch locationInView:self];

CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint, previousPoint2);
CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(location, previousPoint);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, mid1.x, mid1.y);
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
CGRect bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);
CGPathRelease(path);

CGRect drawBox = bounds;

drawBox.origin.x -= self.lineWidth * 2;
drawBox.origin.y -= self.lineWidth * 2;
drawBox.size.width += self.lineWidth * 4;
drawBox.size.height += self.lineWidth * 4;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(totalDrawBox.size, self.opaque, 0.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGAffineTransform affineMoveLeftTop = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-(int)totalDrawBox.origin.x, -(int)totalDrawBox.origin.y);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, affineMoveLeftTop);
float iOSVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue];
if (iOSVersion >= 12) {
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
} else {
    [self.layer renderInContext: context];
}
curImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
CGContextStrokePath(context);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: the same issue with mine. did you fix it?

Comment: @versus I have not fixed yet. When I comment line `[self.layer renderInContext:context];`, the program can draw, but there are lines with many dashed lines and overlapping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [drawRect:/renderInContext: issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129106/drawrect-renderincontext-issues)

Comment: @trungduc It seems they are not the same issues, it works well in my app before iOS12. only crashed in iOS12. that's weird. `renderInContext` will always call drawRect until memory overload, then crash in iOS12.

Comment: Hi ! I have just encountered the same issue. Did you fix it ?

Comment: @Matthieu: I fixed it. In touchMoved() function. I called `[self setNeedsDisplay]` instead of `renderInContext`. I only use `renderInContext` in drawRect() function

Comment: @B2GHCMTrnMinhT Can you show me your code? I still crashed in `drawRect` function with `[self setNeedsDisplay]`. thanks in advance

Comment: @Versus:
In drawRect():
`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
[self.layer renderInContext:context];
.....
CGContextStrokePath(context);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();`
I still use renderInContext in drawRect. However, In touchMoved() function I use `[self setNeedsDisplay]` instead of `renderInContext`

Comment: @B2GHCMTrnMinhT Yep, I know what you mean, and I think our code logics are the same, both using CoreGraphics to draw lines, I want to know that you just removed these code `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawBox.size); ...`, and replaced with `[self setNeedsDisplay]`? can you edit your `touchMoved` code to let me know what you have changed?

Comment: @Versus: I added my code. Hope this helps you!

Comment: @B2GHCMTrnMinhT Thanks a lot ~

Answer (score 3):

My work around is

Don't let layer renderInContext recursive call in drawRect

(My code is swift)

```
var mIsInDrawLoop = false

// -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
...
    if(!mIsInDrawLoop) {
        mIsInDrawLoop = true
        layer.render(in: context)
        // [self.layer renderInContext:context];
        mIsInDrawLoop = false
    }
...
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, I think it is a good solution. easy and clear. By the way, I think we are supposed to find the reason why this happens, and when `renderInContext` will be called in `drawRect`.